# Container View that contains a TableView change number of rows depending number of inputs Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I am new to swift as well as creating iOS apps and I thought I would make a simple app that calculates the averages of the numbers inputted into the TextField. The `averageViewController` also has a container view as well that contains `TableView`. Once the person has hit the "Next" button I would like the TableView to display the numbers that have been inputted. (each cell label has a single number).

This is my segue method in my `averageViewController` as well as the function I am using when the user presses the button:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "sendResult" {
    let inputArray = segue.destinationViewController as! averageTableViewController

    inputArray.arrayFromSegue = average.getArray()
    }

}



@IBAction func nextButton(sender: UIButton) {
    average.arrayInput(((inputTextField.text!) as NSString).doubleValue)
    calcAverage()

    inputTextField.text=nil
}
```

This is the code I made for my `averageTableViewController`:

```
class averageTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var arrayFromSegue = NSMutableArray()
    var arrayUsed = NSMutableArray()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        arrayUsed = arrayFromSegue

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var Cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        Cell.textLabel?.text = String(arrayUsed[indexPath.row])
        return Cell

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayUsed.count
    }
}
```

I have done quite a bit of research and I believe one of my mistakes is that the action segue that I am doing (show) does not produce the correct results.

Comment: what is version of your swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem isn't in segue you do. If you want change number of rows depend on number of input you should update your array data and `reload` your table. In your case you can change like this:

1. Create variable hold your `tableViewController`, in your case can put name is: `inputArray`

   ```
   inputArray = segue.destinationViewController as! averageTableViewController
   ```
2. When you tap `nextbutton` you update array average and assign it to `tableViewConroller` `inputArray and reload it:

   ```
   inputArray.arrayUsed = average.getArray()
   inputArray.tableView.reloadData()
   ```

If you have any problem don't hesitate ask me. I will help you.

You can check my demo:  [Demo](https://github.com/vienvu89/DemoSegueTableController)

Your project leak segue to tableviewcontroller: Please fix project like step below:

- drage segue from average to averagetable

[image]

- make it is embed:

[image]

- Select it and name it `sendResult`

[image]

Comment: I tried what you had suggested but whenever I do inputArray.reload() I get an error saying:

     value of type "averageTableViewController" has no member 'reload' 

also I already had 
"inputArray = segue.destinationViewController as! averageTableViewController" in my button pressed

Comment: @Avi sorry, reloadData() not reload.

Comment: still an error. As I type the only thing that comes up is reloadInputViews(). If I try that my app crashes and I get the:

 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Multi_tool_Calculator.averageTableViewController 0x7ff54cc30e30> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key amount.'

Comment: @Avi you should call function `inputArray.tableView.reloadData() I have create a demo for you. Hope this help.

Comment: Thank You for all your help! The demo was great. My last issue (hopefully) is that I am getting the error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value 

I know this has to do with something being a nil value but for some reason I can not see where the issue is.

Comment: apparently the nil value is my inputArray in the action of my button. 

        inputArray.arrayFromSegue = average.input // this line the error forms 
        inputArray.tableView.reloadData()
for some reason "inputArray" = nil

im not sure if this helps but:

https://gyazo.com/4b90d59b1db5be9cf3e838f31bc0b1cc

Comment: @Avi can you show a part of code or context for it? I think maybe have some problem with your segue or the way you hold reference to it.

Comment: I have uploaded my project here: https://github.com/Attrition18/Multi-tool-Calculator.git tell me if there is any issues with the upload (this is also my first time using gitHub so I am not sure if I did everything correctly)

Comment: @Avi You upload three file keyboard, keyboard.xi and processor. But I see that you don't have segue to averagetableviewcontroller

Comment: I don't know which action segue to use honestly each one I have tried gave me undesirable results

Comment: @Avi update your leak file and I will try hep you debug. I have freetime  now.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean by leak file.

Comment: @Avi your git track leak somefile

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for all your help. It finally works. I can't begin to express my thanks enough. Thank you